# CentOS 7 LibVirt/KVM guest NIC limited 100Mbps/100BaseT

Tags: linux, centos7, kvm-virtualization

Running a KVM CentOS 7 guest on a CentOS 7 host. Everything is swell except the guest NIC seems to be stuck at 100Mbps. From dmesg:

```
[   17.217541] 8139cp 0000:00:03.0 ens3: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x05E1
```

```
Settings for ens3:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
```

The host server shows 10Gbps:

```
[   25.654105] bnx2x 0000:18:00.0 em1: NIC Link is Up, 10000 Mbps full duplex, Flow control: none
```

```
Settings for em1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full 
                                10000baseKR/Full
```

Any idea why the guest would not support 10Gbps or even 1Gbps?

Comment: it looks for me that you choosen a rtl 8139 driver instead of virtio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you selected "rtl8139" (`8139cp`) as device model to be emulated as network interface card rather "virtio". This still can be changed e.g. using `virt-manager` or `virsh`. However it requires a poweroff of the virtual machine, as legacy hardware like RTL8139 can not be hotplugged.

See the [screenshot](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide-en-US/images/1b29613bc9e54c5b8a180eaac9f5b7b5/New-virtio-NIC.png) at [5.3 Using KVM virtio Drivers for Network Interface Devices](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/index#sect-KVM_Para_virtualized_virtio_Drivers-Using_KVM_virtio_drivers_for_NIC_devices) of the official Red Hat documentation for which value to change using `virt-manager` (there is also an example for `virsh`).

Comment: Thanks! That was it! And very easy to fix, using virsh edit, especially since they're all new and not in use yet. While I was there I also set the drives to virtio.
In case anyone is wondering, these VMs were installed with virt-install, without specifying any particular driver/model on the command line for 'model' or 'bus' type

Comment: I'm usually not using `virt-install`, but I think passing `--os-variant rhel7` could lead to VirtIO by default.